# Execute initialization code in EJB3.1

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.1

I am currently migrating to EJB3.1 after using Spring for many years. One thing I would like to implement in EJB, for which I couldn't find a matching pattern yet is my MigrationManager.
In Spring I had a bean that dealt with database schema and data migration. For this I implemented a Spring BeanFactoryPostProcessor because this way I had the database connection injected, but the JPA system is not yet initialized. So I could perform all migration steps and then have the application finishing starting.

How can I do something like this in EJB3.1 (Using CDI ... if this is of importance)

Chris

Comment: Maybe possible to do a @Singleton+@Startup datamigration-ejb in a separate app that is deployed in strict order before your real app. But I really dont have experience with this.

Comment: But there must be some other solution ... I bet more people have the requirement to update a db schema before starting the JPA Entity Manager. Eventually is there any Hibernate initialization feature I could use? Otherwise at least I have a solid example of something cool you can't do with EJBs ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to run some initialization code from an EJB:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class MigrationManager {
    @PostConstruct
    public void migrate() {
       // do work
    }
}
```

You don't need a separate app for that (as suggested in a comment above).

EntityManagers get instantiated lazily, so as long as you don't inject an `EntityManager` into some other startup code, this should give you a chance to update your database schema before an `EntityManager` is actually hitting the database.

By the way, for database schema migration I'd recommend [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/), which can be triggered by a `ServletContextListener`.

Comment: Well actually the MigrationManager I created for Spring actually works using Liquibase underneath, but allows to define one migration step as a sequence of schma and data migrations. Schema migrations are done via liquibase and data-migration is done via Java classes implementing a special interface. But thanks for the pointer ... I was allready thinking of that PostConstruct thing, but I think I couldn't prevent any other Startup component from accessing the EntityManager. I was thinking of a Decorator and decorating the entity manager and wrapping some init method of the entity manager.